# Nested ItemViews, events not working properly

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have 2 models, implemented via backbone.relational and backbone.localstorage, they're working good.

and I have 2 views, first is a "single item" viewer and the second one is an item view with a render function to view my single item view in the way I want, the problem is events not working, neither in parent view nor in single item view.
I've reimplemented that code in the similar way to show you how it's not working ( code is in coffeescript ) :

```
log = console.log

class $.Girl extends Backbone.RelationalModel
  localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage 'gals'
  initialize: -> if typeof @get('id') is 'undefined' then @save() else @fetch()

class $.Girls extends Backbone.RelationalModel
  localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage 'gals'
  relations:[{
    type: Backbone.HasMany
    key: 'gals'
    relatedModel: $.Girl
    includeInJson: 'id'
  }]
  initialize: ->
    if typeof @get('id') is 'undefined' then @save() else @fetch()
    @fetchRelated()

class $.GirlView extends Marionette.ItemView
  tagName: 'tr'
  template: (data)-> '<td>'+data.name+' -- '+data.age+'<button>Love</button></td>'
  initialize: ->
    @listenTo @model,'change',@render

  events:
    'click button': 'sayLove'

  sayLove : -> log 'I Love YOU!'

class $.GirlsView extends Marionette.ItemView
  template: (data)->
    '<table>
        <thead><tr><th>My Gals</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
        <tfoot><tr><td>I Love Them!</td></tr></tfoot>
      </table>'
  initialize: (options)->
    @models = @model.get('gals').models
    @list = []
    self = @
    _.each @models,(girl)-> self.list.push new $.GirlView {model:girl}

  events:
    'click th': 'hello'
  render: ->
    @$el.html(@template {})
    self = @
    _.each @list,(girl)->
      girl.delegateEvents()
      self.$('tbody').append girl.render().$el

  hello: -> log 'hello'

gal1 = new $.Girl {name:'gal1',age:'22',id:'gal-1'}
gal2 = new $.Girl {name:'gal2',age:'19',id:'gal-2'}
gals = new $.Girls {title:'maGals',id:'gals-1',gals:['gal-1','gal-2']}

gv = new $.GirlsView {model:gals}
gv.render()
$('body').append gv.$el.html()
```

It's kinda hello world for me.
Any idea how can I implement nested itemViews with events working or any other idea for this snippet is appreciated.

Comment: Could you try changing `$('body').append gv.$el.html()`? Instead, put `$('body').append @$el` at the very beginning of your render view. And put the `girl.delegateEvents()` after the `self.$('tbody').append girl.render().$el`. The point is, I'm not sure the bindings can be done on elements yet-to-be-inserted in the DOM.

Comment: Oh, very very thank you! there is no need to use delegateEvents().

Comment: So this first change worked? I'll update my answer for future reference.

Comment: the problem was that html(), $('body').append gv.$el worked well, in my original app code I made that mistake too. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling delegateEvents after appending your child views:

```
self.$('tbody').append girl.render().el
girl.delegateEvents()
// or maybe @delegateEvents()? the context should be the child here
```

**Edit:**

Change `$('body').append gv.$el.html()` to `$('body').append @$el`.

Comment: what is the child, girl for this code? another problem for me is even the GirlsView events ( parent view for GirlView ) is not calling on click or any other event I create!

Comment: Sorry, yes. Dunno where I got this child.

Comment: I tried out that, but not working, I'll edit question with models and sample of use.

Comment: If you could also post the javascript code, I could make use of it I guess :)

Comment: ok, now the code is like what you said but still not working! Full code with models and data is there!

Comment: Eventually make a jsfiddle while I'm having a look, that could really help too :p